# Why can't I reach my admin login and logout pages from my index.html template

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I'm confused as to why I'm unable to reach my flask-admin login and logout pages from my base template. Could someone assist me?

Here is my flask-admin code taken and modified slightly from an example I found on github:

```
class MyAdminIndexView(AdminIndexView):
  @expose('/')
  def index(self):
    if not flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('.login_view'))
    return super(MyAdminIndexView, self).index()

@expose('/login/', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
  def login_view(self):
    form = LoginForm(request.form)
    if helpers.validate_form_on_submit(form):
        user = form.get_user()
        flask_login.login_user(user)

    if flask_login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('.index'))
    self._template_args['form'] = form
    return super(MyAdminIndexView, self).index()

@expose('/logout/')
  def logout_view(self):
    flask_login.logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('.login_view'))
```

admin = Admin(app, name='BlackDuck Flock', index_view=MyAdminIndexView(), template_mode='bootstrap3')

I can't figure out how to reach these views from my `templates/index.html`

I've tried these options in my view for the navbar:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href={{ url_for('.login_vew') }}>Login</a></li>
    <li><a href={{ url_for('.logout_view') }}>Logout</a></li>
 </ul>

 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href={{ url_for('admin.login_vew') }}>Login</a></li>
    <li><a href={{ url_for('admin.logout_view') }}>Logout</a></li>
 </ul>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href={{ url_for('/login_vew') }}>Login</a></li>
    <li><a href={{ url_for('/logout_view') }}>Logout</a></li>
 </ul>

# At this point I'm guessing now......

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href={{ url_for('/admin/login') }}>Login</a></li>
    <li><a href={{ url_for('./admin/logout') }}>Logout</a></li>
 </ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Basically all I needed to do was create a wrap around for the admin interface like so:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
  return redirect(url_for('admin.login_view'))

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
  return redirect(url_for('admin.logout_view'))
```